# Can I use 120 ohm impedance cable for ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, wired-networking

Can I use existing telco cable in my building for ethernet networking (100 Mbit link) ? Cables have a marking 120 Ohm, 350 MHz, and contain 4 twisted pairs. What could be possible downsides ?

I have actually successfully connected 2 devices via this cable (PC to switch) and everything seemed to work fine, but I also read that CAT 5E cable has 100 ohm impedance so I am not sure if using this cable was a bad idea for some reason (eg. unstable connection, possibility of equipment damage).

I know that not using a cat 5/6 cable means I won't be able to get maximum possible connection speed, but I would like to use this existing infrastructure if possible.

Thanks

Comment: As long as the cables are not in use, connected to another device, and the pin-out on either end corresponds to CAT 5e, there's little likelihood of doing any harm. The only  way to discover how this works, without knowing your Ethernet adapter specs, how well the cable is terminated, whether the cable is kinked or compressed behind a wall, etc. is to experiment. That said, though, the impedance tolerance for CAT 5e is 15%, so the telco wiring might even be within tolerance, if it's a bit low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without providing us with the cable markings, this will not be an authoritive answer. (Should be printed on the cable every foot or so.)

Most telecommunication cables are within +15/-15% of the specified ohm value, which can be translated to AC impedance for data, and ohms DC if P.O.E is used. Both actually apply when you are using POE. (Your cable is listed as 120ohms, so -15% would put it very close to the specification for Ethernet, but if it's +15% it would be close to 40% over the specification)

As far as I am aware, the OHM (impedance) rating & frequency of transmission, (also possibly twists per inch) are what determine the total distance in Ethernet, and 25/50 pair telecommunications wiring. Voltage drop in alternating-current circuits is directly related to impedance. In alternating-current circuits, opposition to current flow occurs because of resistance.  So, the take away here is: voltage drop in an AC circuit is the product of the current and the impedance of the circuit.

In laymen's terms, you may not get the specified distance for 100-base-T or 1000-baseT equipment. The twists per inch and total bandwidth of the cabling determine the speed of transmission. (Not counting the equipment interfaces of course) 350mhz is actually 100mhz better than the specification for CAT-6, but again the twist interval & shielding (if any) will also determine the actual throughput.

As far as damaging the equipment, it's highly unlikely this would happen with any equipment made in the past 5 to 8 years, as even most cheap consumer grade gear is using "green ethernet" technology, which can adjust voltages on the wire for the total distance it calculates for the wire in use.

I would personally try Gigabit Ethernet over the cable, use jperf or similar to test the actual throughput. Just because your NIC tells you it's connected at 1000Mbps doesn't mean it will reach that data rate.

Regards,

References:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair

http://www.xmultiple.com/xwebsite-forum24.htm

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-Efficient_Ethernet

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_drop